# BASH Script syntax error using grep on variable containing special characters

Tags: bash, if-statement, syntax, grep

```
#!/bin/bash

password=$1

 if [[ $# -gt 1 || $1 = "-h" ]]; then
            echo 'Usage: pw | pw -h | pw password'
            echo "Note:   Valid passwords must be between 8-16 characters long.
            contain at least 1 digit
            contain at least 1 lowercase letter
            contain at least 1 uppcase letter
            contain one of @ # $ % & * + - ="
 fi
if [[ $# -lt 1 ]]; then
    regex='0-9A-Z@*+#$%&a-z'
    password=$( cat /dev/urandom | tr -dc '0-9A-Z@*+#$%&a-z' | head -c $(( 8 + $RANDOM % 8 )))
    check=$( echo $password | grep -o ['@*+#$%&'] | wc -m )
    while [[ $check  -gt 2 || $check -lt 1 ]]
            do
            password=$( cat /dev/urandom | tr -dc '0-9A-Z@*+#$%&a-z' | head -c $(( 8 + $RANDOM % 8 )))
            check=$( echo $password | grep -o ['@*+#$%&'] | wc -m )
    done
    echo $password
 fi
if [[ $# = 1 ]]; then
    password=$1
    echo "$password" | grep [A-Z][a-z]
    if [[ $? = 1 ]]; then

    echo "Password must contain at least one upper or lowercase characer"
            exit 2
    fi

    echo "$password" | grep [0-9]
    if [[ $? = 1 ]]; then

    echo "Password must contain at least one digit"
            exit 3
    fi

    if [[ `echo "$password" | grep -o ['@#$%&*+-'] 2>/dev/null` -gt 2 ]]; then
            echo "You must only use one special character"
            exit 4
    fi

    if [[ `echo "$password" | grep -o ['\@\#\$\%\&\*\+\-'] 2>/dev/null` -lt 1 ]]; then

    echo "Password must contain at least one special character"
            exit 5
    fi
    woc=$( echo "$password" | wc -m )
    if [[ $woc -lt 8 || $woc -gt 16 ]]; then

    echo "Password must be between 8 and 16 characters"
            exit 6
    fi
 echo "$1 is a valid password"
fi
```

The first part of this script works perfectly and generates a random password 8-16 characters long with only one special character. Problems are on line 40 and 45, both giving me the same error "Syntax error: expecting operand "[special character]". I have tried creating variables and calling them, using the $? variable to check output and more. Unfortunately this error stays consistently even though the script does run correctly.

Comment: I would suggest you reduce the amount of code in your answer, and better identify the code that does not work how you expect, what the exact inputs are, etc.

Comment: also along with ^ useful comment, copy paste your script in http://www.shellcheck.net to fix trivial syntax issues and code vulnerabilities

Comment: In addition to the problem you're seeing, there are a bunch of potential problems due to improper quoting. `$password` should *always* be in double-quotes, and your `grep` patterns should be single-quoted to prevent the shell from matching them as filename wildcards. Also, the regex `[A-Z][a-z]` matches an uppercase letter immediately followed by a lowercase letter; if you want to match any letter, use `'[A-Za-z]'`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I fixed the code, it was a simple mistake. I forgot to include wc -m.

```
if [[ `echo "$password" | grep [\@\#\$\%\&\*\+\-] | wc -m` -lt 2 ]]
```

Comment: @kieran-oconnor  I like the guys that fix yourself :). **If you find a mistake. no problem start over**